# This is the code for inserting/creating a binary tree? but the display() function is not displaying anything? what am I missing?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, tree, binary-tree

There is a insert function which inserts in the tree recursively and display function for displaying the output.
the display() function is not displaying anything? Is there any error which I'm missing out?
please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{   int val;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

node *root=NULL;

void insert(node *root1,int value)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        node *temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->val=value;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        root=temp;
        root1=root;
        return;
    }


    if(root1==NULL && root!=NULL)
    {
        node *temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->val=value;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        root1=temp;
        return;
    }


    if(root1->val >value)
    {
        insert(root1->left, value);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(root1->right, value);
    }

    return;
}


void display(node *root1)
{
    if(root1==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    while(root1 !=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", root1->val);
        display(root1->left);
        display(root1->right);
        return;
    }
}


int main()
{
    insert(root,4);
    insert(root,12);
    insert(root,2);
    insert(root,55);
    display(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Actually I'm new to programming and trying to implement trees. New suggestions are also welcome! Thank you

//EDIT

```
void sayHi(int* nums){
    printf("hello");
    printf("my address is %d \n",nums);
    printf("val of nums[2] is%d\n", nums[2]);
    nums[2]=30;   
}



void someFunct(int* nums, int numsSize){
    nums[2]=50;
    sayHi(nums);
    printf("address is %d\n",nums);
    printf("val of nums[2] is%d\n", nums[2]); 
}
```

input i.e., nums =[0,0,0,0,0]

output for above code is

```
hellomy address is 16 
val of arr[2] is50
address is 16
val of arr[2] is30
```

Here we are passing sayHi(nums)?and it still works? Address of nums is same in someFunct and sayHi?

Does passing arg like someFunct(&ptr) only happens for structures?

Comment: The problem is that the global variable `struct node *root=NULL;` is being shadowed by the function parameter `insert(node *root, ...)`. The line `root=temp;` changes the parameter's value. It does not change the value of the global variable. So the `root` that `main` uses is always NULL.

Comment: User### is right: ‘*root1’ needs to be ‘**root1’.

Comment: @user3386109
  why is this happening? isn't it already a pointer? it must pass by reference?

Comment: You need to pass the address of the pointer to the function, if you want to change the pointer's value in the function. I've added an answer which shows two ways to do this. The answer also shows how to accomplish the task without using a pointer-to-pointer argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

In this method the `root` pointer is declared as a local variable in `main`, and the address of the pointer is passed to the `insert` function. This allows the `insert` function to change the value of `root` in `main`.

The downside of this method is that it involves some of the nastiest syntax in the C language, with `*`s and `&`s sprinkled everywhere, along with an inordinate number of mandatory parentheses.

```
void insert(node **root, int value)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        node *temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->val=value;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        *root = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        if((*root)->val > value)
            insert(&(*root)->left, value);
        else
            insert(&(*root)->right, value);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    node *root=NULL;
    insert(&root,4);
    insert(&root,12);
    insert(&root,2);
    insert(&root,55);
    display(root);
}
```

### Method 2

Similar to method 1, this method also passes the address of the `root` pointer to the `insert` function, but to avoid some of the nasty syntax imposed by pointers-to-pointers, a local pointer `item` is used to access structure contents. This eliminates most of the `*`s and parentheses that were needed in method 1.

The downside of this method is that there are still `&`s sprinkled throughout the code, and it's easy to forget the line `*root = temp;` which updates the caller's pointer.

```
void insert(node **root, int value)
{
    node *item = *root;
    if (item == NULL)
    {
        node *temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->val=value;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        *root = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(item->val > value)
            insert(&item->left, value);
        else
            insert(&item->right, value);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    node *root=NULL;
    insert(&root,4);
    insert(&root,12);
    insert(&root,2);
    insert(&root,55);
    display(root);
}
```

### Method 3

In this method, we return the new `root` pointer from the `insert` function. Thus, the first function parameter can be a simple pointer. This eliminates the nasty syntax found in method 1. There are fewer `*`s, absolutely no `&`s, and no inordinate parentheses.

The downside to this method is that the return value from the function needs to be assigned to the appropriate pointer. That results in a couple of assignments in the `insert` function (at the recursive calls), as well as assignments in `main`.

```
node *insert(node *root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root=malloc(sizeof(node));
        root->val=value;
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->val > value)
            root->left = insert(root->left, value);
        else
            root->right = insert(root->right, value);
    }
    return root;
}

int main(void)
{
    node *root=NULL;
    root = insert(root,4);
    root = insert(root,12);
    root = insert(root,2);
    root = insert(root,55);
    display(root);
}
```

### Boilerplate

Here's the code that when combined with the `insert` and `main` functions from any method above gives a complete set of code that can be compiled and run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{   int val;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

void display(node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", root->val);
        display(root->left);
        display(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay! It cleared a lot of confusion... One more ques... when we mallocate array and pass them then we don't pass like someFunct(&arr) we just pass someFunct(arr)? why is it so?

Comment: I have editted the ques and added the code part for arr which i'm trying to ask? the confusion is why for root we passed ` insert(&root) ` and when I have to pass an array then ` someFunct(nums)` also worked ? @user3386109